# Как сделать проверку процесса по таймеру?

Tags: delphi

Подключаем модуль в uses:

```
tlHelp32;
```

Функция по определению процесса:

```
function FindTask(ExeFileName: string): Integer;
var
  ContinueLoop: LongBool;
  hSnapshot: THandle;
  PE32: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  Result := 0;
  hSnapshot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  PE32.dwSize :=SizeOf(TProcessEntry32);
  ContinueLoop := Process32First(hSnapshot, PE32);
  while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
  begin
    if ((UpperCase(ExtractFileName(PE32.szExeFile)) = UpperCase(ExeFileName)) or (UpperCase(PE32.szExeFile) = UpperCase(ExeFileName))) then
      Result := 1;
    ContinueLoop :=Process32Next(hSnapshot, PE32);
  end;
  CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
end;
```

Ну и подключаем функцию к кнопке:

```
 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   if FindTask('Process.exe') = 1 then
     ShowMessage('Process.exe - запущен!')
   else
     ShowMessage('Process.exe - не запущен!');
 end;
```

Как исправить данную функцию, что бы после нажатия на кнопку, проверка - запущен процесс (**Process.exe**) или нет - осуществлялась после 3 секунды и далее каждые 5 секунд? То есть: нажатие на кнопку, проходит первые **3 секунды**, включается таймер и далее проверка осуществляется каждые **5 секунд.**

Comment: Татьяна, Вам нужно *ровно* 3 и 5 секунд соответственно или допускается небольшая погрешность?

Comment: @Dima, Не обязательно, можно и с погрешностью,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Татьяна, могу предложить такой вариант.

Находим в палитре компонентов вкладку *System*. Открываем ее, ищем в списке компонентов `TTimer`.  Добавляем его на форму, в инспекторе объектов находим свойство `Interval`. Оно способно принимать значение задержки в миллисекундах. Для установки задержки в 5 секунд необходимо присвоить этому свойству значение 5000 (1 секунда = 1000 миллисекунд).

Затем дважды кликаем по компоненту `TTimer` на форме и пишем обработчик кода - то есть Вашу функцию поиска процесса.

Затем переходим к обработчику кнопки запуска процесса поиска.
Двойной клик по кнопке, пишем следующий код:

```
procedure TForm1.aButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Interval: DWord;
  StartTime: DWord;
  StopTime: DWord;
begin
  // Задаем интервал для отсчета 3-х секунд
  Interval := 3000;

  // Отсчитываем эти секунды...
  StartTime := GetTickCount;
  repeat
    StopTime := GetTickCount;
  until (StopTime - StartTime) >= Interval;

  // Секунды отсчитаны успешно, переходим к первичному поиску процесса
  if FindTask('Process.exe') = 1 then
    ShowMessage('Process.exe - запущен!')
  else
    ShowMessage('Process.exe - не запущен!');

  // Нашли/не нашли, переходим к периодическому поиску процесса,
  // для чего запускаем предварительно настроенный таймер
  Timer1.Enabled := true;
end;
```

Справка по функции `GetTickCount` сообщает нам, что

> The resolution of the GetTickCount function is limited to the resolution of the system timer, which is typically in the range of 10 milliseconds to 16 milliseconds.

Иными словами, точность возвращаемого функцией значения зависит от системного таймера и колеблется в диапазоне от 10 до 16 миллисекунд. В связи с этим нет гарантий того, что *первый* поиск процесса будет выполнен *ровно* спустя 3 секунды. Именно это я имел в виду, когда спрашивал о допустимости погрешности.

То же самое и с компонентом `TTimer`. Для своей работы он (компонент) создает невидимое окно, которое проверяет наличие сообщения `WM_TIMER` в очереди сообщений этого окна. В связи с тем, что, согласно справке

> The WM_TIMER message is a low-priority message.

данное сообщение имеет *низкий приоритет*, то становится решительно невозможно ожидать от таймера точного срабатывания *ровно* через 5 секунд, поскольку сначала будут обработаны сообщения с высоким приоритетом, что гарантирует определенную задержку (минимальную, но все же).

Таким образом, погрешность в отсчете времени будет присутствовать, но на решение Вашей задачи не повлияет.

Источники информации:
[GetTickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx)
[WM_TIMER message](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-timer)

Comment: Отличное решение, сейчас буду и в это коде разбираться :). Спасибо Вам - Дмитрий, и еще многим людям, этого прекрасного сообщества, за то что помогаете в решении разных задач!

Comment: На самом деле всё проще: засовываем эту проверку в таймер, выставляем ему интервал 3 секунды. По нажатию кнопки запускаем таймер. В обработчике Timer1OnTimer() первой строкой выставляем таймеру интервал 5 секунд. Всё. При этом не будет "зависания" формы на 3 секунды при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: @Alekcvp, и получаем двойной вызов `SetTimer` и `KillTimer` - при старте таймера и при назначении нового интервала. Еще один момент: если при включении таймера `Enabled := true` система не создаст таймер (нехватка ресурсов), то есть риск, что **таймер не сработает даже один раз**, а это не есть хорошо. В условии вопроса ведь сказано: *нажатие на кнопку - проверка процесса - запуск таймера с периодической проверкой процесса.* И вообще - это дурной тон: менять интервал таймера из обработчика выполнения таймера. Это мое мнение, но Вы, безусловно, вольны не согласиться и дать свой ответ ;)

Comment: @Dima, ну по моему личному мнению, двойной вызов SetTimer и KillTimer - это ничто по сравнению с зависающим на 3 секунды (при нажатии на кнопку) интерфейсом. И, заодно, посмотрите сколько процессорного времени будет потреблять ваше приложение в эти 3 секунды. И если системе настолько плохо, что не хватает ресурсов даже на таймер, то не сработавший таймер будет наименьшей вашей проблемой. Мы же не про Windows 95 говорим.

Comment: @Alekcvp, можно долго спорить по поводу циклов, вызовов, потребления процессорного времени. НО. Условие вопроса я выполнил - *таймер запускается по истечении 3-х секунд*. По поводу  *заморозки* формы - можно прибегнуть к `Application.ProcessMessages`. Да, не самый гладкий вариант, но все-таки для 3-х секундной задержки подходит вполне. И снова: *модифицировать объект из обработчика этого же объекта - моветон*.

Comment: @Alekcvp, кстати существует несколько дополнительных способов решения задачи: использовать `TThread` - не надо таймеров и скрытых окон; сформировать цикл с временной задержкой (грубый и нехороший вариант - но рабочий). Если Вы уверены, что Ваш вариант с одним таймером жизнеспособен - прошу Вас, опубликуйте здесь ответ. Но мы не на дуэли, так что разойдемся без стрельбы ;)